# VBA copy values from multiple sheets based on multiple criteria into one worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste, criteria

Dears!

I have managed to modify a VBA code with the following result.

I can have multiple criteria for which my code search to different workbooks and if criteria meets then brings the required values to a new worksheet for each criteria value.

What I want to achieve is to bring all the values to one Worksheet Named Data (Workbook: Macros) .

So the first step is to replace the Row: Set wOut = Worksheets.Add with: Set wOut = Workbooks("Macros.xlsm").Sheets("Data").

However I'm not sure how to continue in order the values from my second criteria not to overwrite the previous ones.

Any assistance is more than welcome!

```
Sub SearchFolders()

Dim fso As Object
Dim fld As Object
Dim strSearch As String
Dim strPath As String
Dim strFile As String
Dim wOut As Worksheet
Dim wbk As Workbook
Dim wks As Worksheet
Dim lRow As Long
Dim rFound As Range
Dim strFirstAddress As String

On Error GoTo ErrHandler
Application.ScreenUpdating = False


strPath = "C:\Users\cmkon\Desktop\CAMS"
strSearch = InputBox("Enter Criteria")

Dim MyArray() As String, I As Variant

MyArray = Split(strSearch, ";")


For Each I In MyArray


Set wOut = Worksheets.Add
lRow = 1
With wOut
    .Cells(lRow, 1) = "Workbook"
    .Cells(lRow, 2) = "Worksheet"
    .Cells(lRow, 3) = "Cell"
    .Cells(lRow, 4) = "Text in Cell"
    .Cells(lRow, 5) = "Instructions"
    .Cells(lRow, 6) = "WS#"
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set fld = fso.GetFolder(strPath)


    strFile = Dir(strPath & "\*.xls*") 'here defines which files to check
    Do While strFile <> ""
        Set wbk = Workbooks.Open _
          (Filename:=strPath & "\" & strFile, _
          UpdateLinks:=0, _
          ReadOnly:=True, _
          AddToMRU:=False)


        For Each wks In wbk.Worksheets
        Set rFound = wks.UsedRange.Find(I)
      
                    
            If Not rFound Is Nothing Then
                strFirstAddress = rFound.Address
            End If
            Do
                If rFound Is Nothing Then
                    Exit Do
                Else
                    lRow = lRow + 1
                   .Cells(lRow, 1) = wbk.Name
                    .Cells(lRow, 2) = wks.Name
                    .Cells(lRow, 3) = rFound.Address
                    .Cells(lRow, 4) = rFound.Value
                   .Cells(lRow, 5) = rFound.Offset(, -1).Value
                   .Cells(lRow, 6) = lRow - 1


                End If
                Set rFound = wks.Cells.FindNext(After:=rFound)
            Loop While strFirstAddress <> rFound.Address
        Next


        wbk.Close (False)
        strFile = Dir
    Loop
    .Columns("A:F").EntireColumn.AutoFit
End With


Next I

MsgBox "Done"

ExitHandler:
Set wOut = Nothing
Set wks = Nothing
Set wbk = Nothing
Set fld = Nothing
Set fso = Nothing
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Exit Sub


ErrHandler:
MsgBox Err.Description, vbExclamation
Resume ExitHandler


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

please try with below code, i just replaced the needed lines to acomplish what you need:

```
Sub SearchFolders()

  Dim fso As Object
  Dim fld As Object
  Dim strSearch As String
  Dim strPath As String
  Dim strFile As String
  Dim wOut As Worksheet
  Dim wbk As Workbook
  Dim wks As Worksheet
  Dim lRow As Long
  Dim rFound As Range
  Dim strFirstAddress As String

    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False


    strPath = "C:\Users\cmkon\Desktop\CAMS"
    strSearch = InputBox("Enter Criteria")

    Dim MyArray() As String, I As Variant

    MyArray = Split(strSearch, ";")


    For Each I In MyArray

     'in previous code a new worksheet was added to 
     'the workbook that contains the code, new 
     'version contains "Data" worksheet
     Set wOut = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")
         
     With wOut

          'append new information at the bottom
          lRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
          
          'you'd probably won't need to re-create 
          'headers each time so you can remove these 
          'lines: 
         '.Cells(lRow, 1) = "Workbook"
         '.Cells(lRow, 2) = "Worksheet"
         '.Cells(lRow, 3) = "Cell"
         '.Cells(lRow, 4) = "Text in Cell"
         '.Cells(lRow, 5) = "Instructions"
         '.Cells(lRow, 6) = "WS#"
            
            Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
            Set fld = fso.GetFolder(strPath)


            strFile = Dir(strPath & "\*.xls*") 'here defines which files to check
            Do While strFile <> ""
               Set wbk = Workbooks.Open _
               (Filename:=strPath & "\" & strFile, _
                UpdateLinks:=0, _
                ReadOnly:=True, _
                AddToMRU:=False)


        For Each wks In wbk.Worksheets
          Set rFound = wks.UsedRange.Find(I)
  
                
        If Not rFound Is Nothing Then
            strFirstAddress = rFound.Address
        End If
        Do
            If rFound Is Nothing Then
                Exit Do
            Else
                'lRow = lRow + 1
               .Cells(lRow, 1) = wbk.Name
                .Cells(lRow, 2) = wks.Name
                .Cells(lRow, 3) = rFound.Address
                .Cells(lRow, 4) = rFound.Value
               .Cells(lRow, 5) = rFound.Offset(, -1).Value
               .Cells(lRow, 6) = lRow - 1


            End If
            Set rFound = wks.Cells.FindNext(After:=rFound)
        Loop While strFirstAddress <> rFound.Address
    Next


    wbk.Close (False)
    strFile = Dir
Loop
.Columns("A:F").EntireColumn.AutoFit

End With


Next I

MsgBox "Done"

 ExitHandler:
 Set wOut = Nothing
 Set wks = Nothing
 Set wbk = Nothing
 Set fld = Nothing
 Set fso = Nothing
 Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Exit Sub


 ErrHandler:
 MsgBox Err.Description, vbExclamation
 Resume ExitHandler


End Sub
```

Regards!

Comment: Hello @EdmundoCanales, Thank you for your feedback! however doesn't work properly. It brings only one row for Each I

Comment: I slightly changed your suggestion.  'lRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row' and i made active again the row 'lRow = lRow + 1'. It is working now but i need to figure out something about my last column which is the auto-numbering for each I. Thanks!